# How to increase width of slide content?

Tags: css, gitpitch

Or specify the format to 16:9 for example?

I need to fit more text (quotes that I can't really abbreviate) onto a slide. Trying various combinations of `.reveal .slides` and `section>*` with `width: 1280px` or `150%` (derived from [gitpitch/wiki/Slideshow-Custom-CSS#Example-2](https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/wiki/Slideshow-Custom-CSS)) didn't help.

Comment: You need to provide a snippet.

Comment: `.reveal .slides {
    width: 1280px;
}
` or `.reveal .slides section>* {
    width: 1280px;
}
` is what I tried, plus other values for `width`. I'm not sure whether this is a CSS mistake on my part, or a limitation of GitPitch.

Comment: To make it possible for other people to debug this issue, you should provide a working snippet (demo, for example on jsfiddle) that reproduces entire thing.

Comment: code: https://github.com/katrinleinweber/gm17-data-integitry
rendered: https://gitpitch.com/katrinleinweber/gm17-data-integitry (3rd slide for example)

Answer (score 7):

This question was asked quite some time ago but I'm going to answer it now (albeit late) as the answer might be helpful for new visitors to this SO thread in the future.

The 3rd slide in the sample presentation that was provided makes use of a Markdown blockquote. That blockquote is ultimately rendered as a HTML blockquote with a default `width` css style set to 70%. That default 70% width comes from the default GitPitch/reveal.js white theme.

So to fit more text into quotes you do not want to use custom CSS try and change the width of the slide itself. You want to use custom CSS to modify the default theme to make blockquotes use more than 70% width of the slide.

This is achieved very simply using the following CSS snippet:

```
.reveal blockquote { width: 90% }
```

In this case, if you used this custom CSS your slideshow would render quotes using 90% of the slide width. In that way you could fit more text in your quotes on a single slide.

To use custom CSS with your GitPitch presentation see the following [GitPitch Wiki page for details](https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/wiki/Slideshow-Custom-CSS).

Comment: I have tried your approach on this project with no luck: https://github.com/AlexITC/gitpitch-test

Comment: The answer provided above answers the original question which was how can they fit more text within a blockquote. The solution indicated used CSS styling to adjust the width of HTML blockquotes within a presentation. Your sample presentation is not using blockquotes. It appears to be using code blocks. So you need to apply custom CSS styling to adjust the width of the code block. Use .reveal pre { width: 100%; }.